# Out of Memory when running PHP script from command line

Tags: php

I have this PHP script I'm trying to run once from a command line to fix some values in a MySQL database.  So it's running over a lot of queries.  I run it, and it goes for a while, until it runs out of memory.  Is that kind of thing expected for running a PHP script with a whole lot of MySQL queries, or is this due to some kind of memory leak?

```
$statement = 'SELECT users.language, users.created AS user_created, 
    posts.created, posts.id, blogs.user_id, posts.blog_id FROM users
    JOIN blogs ON users.id = blogs.user_id
    JOIN posts ON blogs.id = posts.blog_id
    ORDER BY users.id
    LIMIT %d, %d';

$limit = 100;
$page = 0;
$rows = array();

while($page == 0 || !empty($rows)) {
    echo 'Fixing posts ' . ($page * $limit + 1) . ' to ' . ($page * $limit + $limit + 1) . "\n";
    $rows = $db->prepare($statement)
            ->bindValue($page * $limit)
            ->bindValue($limit)
            ->execute();

    foreach($rows as $row) {  /*Do a bunch of stuff to fix the data*/ }
    $page++;
}
```

Edit:  I threw in an `echo memory_get_usage() , "\n";` before the $page++, then tried commenting out the queries I do in the for loop, and I found that inner queries are taking up extra memory per loop that aren't getting reallocated.

Comment: How can you bind to %d, %d values in limit? Are you using a custom db abstraction library?

Comment: $db is a custom class.

Comment: generally speaking, you shouldn't be preparing your select statement inside the loop. You prepare/bind it ONCE **OUTSIDE** the loop, then just re-execute it as many times as you need inside the loop. re-preparing it like that is a waste of resources and negates one of the major benefits of prepared statements.

Comment: @MarcB Good point, though it's not actually a prepared statement.  The custom class (which I didn't write) simply calls that function prepare, but this is sadly written for a server running php 5.1.  >.<

Comment: @kai: shouldn't matter. mysqli's "prepare" has been in PHP since 5.0 and in PDO since 5.1.0. If this is actually using mysql under the hood, then you've got a bigger problem.

Comment: If this is actually using mysql under the hood, then you're lucky to have this single wrapper class which you can relatively easily modify to use PDO. The one who wrote it was a visionary. ;) Nevertheless, it looks like ->execute currently returns all the data. Maybe you can use one of the fetch functions so you only get the data for the row you are working with.

Comment: @GolezTrol "The one who wrote it was a visionary." -- If only I could agree with you, though yes, at least they wrote a wrapper class for this.  >.<

Comment: @GolezTrol  ->execute does return all the data for the query, but I am  breaking it up by paginating it.... so I wouldn't think that should make a huge difference..?

Comment: Oh...my...  So I just found the answer.  In the DB class, in the execute function, it was adding data to $_SESSION for debugging purposes.  Yikes.  Thanks everyone for the help!  And yes, I'll probably look into rewriting the DB class in the future, now knowing 5.1 supports mysqli after all.